# How to query with same column in WHERE and HAVING

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Table has [user_id, city_id].

I want to find out users who satisfy following constraints:
- They are present at least in N number of cities
- They are present in at least one of given sets of cities

For obvious reasons, we cannot have

```
select user_id 
from my_table 
where city_id in ('A', 'B') 
group by user_id 
having count(city_id) > 3;
```

This works if I query using INTERSECT:

```
(select user_id from my_table where city_id in ('A', 'B')) 
INTERSECT 
(select user_id from my_table group by user_id having count(city_id) > 3);
```

(Similar query can be constructed using `JOIN` clause)

However, both of these solutions strike me as in-elegant, and I am thinking there should be some neat solution that I am missing?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: . . I am unclear.  Do you want *both* cities (which is how I read your description)?  Or do you want *any* of the cities (which is what your code does)?

Comment: Any of the cities. I will update description to match that

Comment: Some sample table data and the expected result would help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and `having`.  Here is one method:

```
select user_id
from my_table
group by user_id
having count(*) > 3 and
       count(*) filter (where city_id in ('A', 'B')) = 2;
```

This assumes that the user/city pairs are unique.  If not, you can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select user_id
from my_table
group by user_id
having count(distinct city_id) > 3 and
       count(distinct city_id) filter (where city_id in ('A', 'B')) = 2;
```

The above assumes that you want both `'A'` and `'B'`.  If you want at least one of them:

```
select user_id
from my_table
group by user_id
having count(*) > 3 and
       count(*) filter (where city_id in ('A', 'B')) >= 1;
```